# Using whodunnit to get User Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

On my home page i display the latest updates using papertrail.

Controller

```
@contributions = PaperTrail::Version.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

View

```
<% @contributions.each do |v| %>
    <h2><%= v.item.name %><small>by </small></h2>
    <% v.changeset.each do |data| %>
      <h4><%= data %></h4>
    <% end %>
    <%= v.whodunnit %>
<% end %>
```

Here i get the associated user but only the ID with whodunnit, but i would like to get a user instance to get a **username**. So insted of v.whodunnit i would like v.user.username.

I have been looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239835/paper-trail-versioning) but cant seem to figure out a way create the relation between a version and a user.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions, :foreign_key => 'whodunnit', :class_name => "PaperTrail::Version"
end
```

Version model

```
class Version < PaperTrail::Version
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'whodunnit'
end
```

**EDIT**

I get this when I have <%= v.user %> in view

```
undefined method `user' for #<PaperTrail::Version:0x007fb24c08e868>
```

Comment: What are the problems with your current version?

Comment: I get undefined method 'user' when trying to get v.user in my view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative way to do it:

```
class Version < PaperTrail::Version
    ...

    def user
         User.find(whodunnit) if whodunnit
    end  
end
```

If you need to add user model to the `PaperTrail::Version` class itself, then add a new initializer to your app:

**config/initializers/papertrail_monkey_patch.rb**

```
module PaperTrail
    class Version
        def user
            User.find(whodunnit) if whodunnit
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: When i try to run <%= v.user %> with your method i get the same error as i did above. undefined method `user' for #<PaperTrail::Version:0x007fb24c1d7eb8>

Comment: I guess, I understood the problem. You `v` variable is of class `PaperTrail::Version` and not your custom `Version`. You need to monkey patch `PaperTrail::Version` class.

Comment: Ok thanks, any idea of how i can do this? Mind updating your answer?

Answer (score 5):

An updated version of this for Rails 5.X

```
# config/initializers/paper_trail.rb
PaperTrail::Rails::Engine.eager_load!

module PaperTrail
  class Version < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the relationship to the version model

**config/initializers/paper_trail.rb**

```
    # paper trail config ...
    # ...

    module PaperTrail
      class Version < ::ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

add a model

```rb
class PaperTrailVersion < PaperTrail::Version
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#6a-custom-version-classes) on adding your own custom version model:

```rb
class UserVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
end
```

And then specify the custom model in the class you're tracking changes on:

```rb
class Contribution
  has_paper_trail versions: {class_name: 'UserVersion'}
end
```

Doing this will allow you to also eager load the associated users if you need to display many versions at once:

```rb
Contribution.versions.includes(:user)
```